# WPF Control Loaded Event fires before children are created

Tags: wpf

I have an event handler for the "Loaded" event of a control in which I alter the properties of the one of the visual children.  For years this has worked fine for me; My handler gets the child of the type it needs, alters the padding and all is well.

But now I've started using this control on a page of a TabControl. The page is one of several I create at once and it is not initially showing.  For this page, the Loaded event fires before the user activates the page.  But when my Loaded handler is called, there are literally zero visual children.  The VisualTreeHelper reports that the count of children is 0.

Yet later on when click on the tab and make the page visible,  I can see the control and all of its children have been created.  So apparently they've been created *after* the Loaded event is fired.

Is there some other event I can hook on to to be sure that a control's children have been created?

This is the XAML I use

```
<tk:RadColorPicker 
    Margin="5,0"
    SelectedColor="{Binding Settings.LiveImageHighlightColor, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    Loaded="RadColorPicker_OnLoaded"/>
```

And this is the handler:

```
private void RadColorPicker_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!(sender is RadColorPicker rcp))
        return;

    var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(rcp);

    // Other code here where I get the child of the type I want and change its padding
    // But it's irrelevant to this question because the count = 0 in the error case
}
```

I've read the MS guidance on this and several threads on SO.  They all point to "Loaded" as the event I want

Comment: On Loaded is when the UI element is ready to interact, however it doesn't mean that the children elements are ready. I have my doubts that this is the event you are looking for

Comment: @Demon - i dont think thats right - I think you're talking about the Initialized event, Loaded event fires after all children are initialized and just before rendering. The databinding already has a chance to run by the time first render takes place. Loaded event fires after the tree is built & initialized, data binding has run & its connected to the rendering surface and just not rendered yet - thats when it fires. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mikehillberg/the-loaded-event-and-the-initialized-event

Comment: @Demon see also [Object Lifetime Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/object-lifetime-events)

Comment: `TabControl` can behave different than you may expect. It is generally possible that the Loaded event is called more than once, which is true for the TabControl, especially when switching tabs. Are you sure the event is not called again? You can alternatively listen to the Loaded event of the TabControl which should be raised on each content switch. Or another solution could be to listen to your control's LayoutUpdated event. It's raised multiple times during the layout process (which includes adding and removing children to the element tree), so you need to filter this event.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I did put a breakpoint in the handler to be sure and unfortunately no, it is not called again.  The LayoutUpdated sounds like a possibility.  Not sure how I would filter out the redundancies though since this is also something I had in a style's EventSetter.  (Maybe use the "Tag" property to remember if I'd made my change)